# install windows 7/8 from .iso in a usb flash drive usind debian

Tags: windows, debian, usb-drive

I know it's although a very simple task .
I am working on Debian system , and I have a windows .iso file somewhere on my system .
I want to prepare a bootable usb pen drive for that iso file , while I am on a Debian Run system .

Research Work :-

I have googled a lot on this topic , came to know about Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool but I am on debian and Wine is just not working in there !!!

also , i could n't find any functioning .exe in the YUMI setup for debian .

Comment: Still it's not a question for [so], try [su]. You can flag your own question to be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).